# Access 2016 restrict picture size to 600x800

Tags: image, ms-access, resize

I am building a database and came across an issue that I need help in resolving.  This database the customer wants to be able to link pictures to specific records.  I have it so the pics are not OLE objects but links to a picture folder that will be on their network drive...So essentially the picture will be a hyperlink to the file path....

My question is does anyone know I way I can have the database reformat the picture automatically to 600 x 800 size, to help save space?  We all know if I don't force the DB to do it for them it will not happen and potentially eat up valuable space, as this DB is expected to get quite large.  So I would like to keep the picture folder as small as possible, giving the database more room.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.image.imageheight

Comment: @RobertHarvey That won't save disk space, just set the displayed image height and width. There's no built-in way in Access to manipulate image files

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WIA libary as shown in [VBA – Resize Image](https://www.devhut.net/2017/01/18/vba-resize-image/) like this:

```vb
Function ResizeImageTo600x800(ByVal PathToImage As String, ByVal PathToResizedImage As String) As Boolean

Dim WiaImgFile As Object 'WIA.ImageFile

Set WiaImgFile = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")

With CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess") 'WIA.ImageProcess
   .Filters.Add .FilterInfos("Scale").FilterID 'Add Scale Filter to ImageProcess

   .Filters(1).Properties("MaximumWidth") = 600 ' Set Width to 600px
   .Filters(1).Properties("MaximumHeight") = 800 'Set Height to 800px
   '.Filters(1).Properties("PreserveAspectRatio") = False ' uncomment if AspectRatio should not be preseved

   WiaImgFile.LoadFile PathToImage ' Load Image
   .Apply(WiaImgFile).SaveFile PathToResizedImage ' Apply Filter and save resized Image

   ResizeImageTo600x800 = True

   Set WiaImgFile = Nothing
End With

End Function
```

Usage:

```vb
If ResizeImageTo600x800("\\path\to\image", "\\path\to\resized\image") then
  Msgbox "ResizeImageTo600x800 successful!"
End If
```

Or:

```vb
ResizeImageTo600x800 "\\path\to\image", "\\path\to\resized\image"
```

Depending on your image types, you may also increase the compression of your image to save space. WIA should support this too (with the Convert Filter and its Quality Property).